# How do I unlock the Air Guardian entry in Ars Magica 2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-direwolf20

I've fought and defeated the Water and Earth guardian, and crafted a fair bit of stuff, but the entry for the Air guardian hasn't opened up.

I tried setting my B:"Staged Compendium" config to false, but it doesn't affect a half completed compendium.

Does anyone have a clue as to what I need to do to unlock that entry?

A list of all the unlock requirements would be great if available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and decompiled it.

SPOILER ALERT!

> The following entries are unlocked when achieving the corresponding
>   level:
>
> - 5:"dungeonsAndExploring","enchantments"
> - 10:"armorMage"
> - 15:"BossWaterGuardian","rituals","inlays","inlays_structure"
> - 20:"armorBattlemage"
> - 25:"BossEarthGuardian"
> - 35:"BossAirGuardian"
> - 45:"BossArcaneGuardian"
> - 55:"BossNatureGuardian"
> - 65:"BossWinterGuardian"
> - 75:"BossFireGuardian"
>
> There are also a few other unlocks:
>
> - When you use chalk for the first time
> - When you cast your first spell
> - When you Learn Summon, True Sight, or Binding in the Oculus
>
> Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: For whatever reason, I didn't actually get it till level 36. Not sure if it was a subtle bug, or if the decompiler did things wrong. Oh well